# Composer Install for Windows-

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, composer-php

So I am trying to install Composer and setup Laravel on my Windows OS how ever I keep getting the same error when I run the install.

To start I selected php.exe as it asks from directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16`

I click next, then install and it will go through like its install then stop and display the error:

```
An error occurred. Clicking Retry may resolve this issue.
Connection error [ERR_CONNECTION]:Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

Request to http://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
Failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
because connection host has failed to respond.
```

Now I'm not sure if I have to sets something up or change something in the php.ini file to make this take place but from what I can tell the site getcomposer.org is unable to communicate with my PC as if I have a firewall up blocking it which my firewall is turned off at the time of installation.

I was unable to find a matching question on stack overflow or in any online search, so I went ahead and thought I'd ask to see if anyone can help out, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface i.e running php from the command line )  uses a different php.ini to the one used by PHP under apache.

Edit the php.ini file that is on your `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16` and make sure you have the extension `php_openssl` and 'php_curl` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can try in a console if pinging the composer.org website works,
like so... `ping composer.org`, if that does not work that explains why the install fails.

Comment: thanks for your suggest, it's let me know if problem from my network

Comment: I'm unable to ping to **getcomposer.org**, probably because of my PC protections, is there any other way ? or at lest some kind of workaround to make it install ?