# Composer is not getting installed windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache, composer-php

I'm trying to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) for on my Window 7 OS but its giving me following error:

```
Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org
Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
Failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

My PHP Configuration is :

PHP Version 5.5.22

Apache 2.2.13

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think there will be issue with secure http connection. Follow steps [here](http://www.naeemrana.com/technology/how-to-install-composer-dependency-manager-for-php-in-windows/) . You can replace URL `https://getcomposer.org/installer` with `https://getcomposer.org/installer`.(`s` removed)

Comment: @Firoz : I already tried that but still its not working. Both from command line and through .exe

Comment: Have you tried exact steps from this URL: `http://www.naeemrana.com/technology/how-to-install-composer-dependency-manager-for-php-in-windows/`. ? if yes then which step you are getting error?

Comment: Yes I tried exact steps. Error is coming when I'm trying to fire this command `php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"`

Comment: May be your IP is blocked by getcomposer.org. Can you hit this URL `https://getcomposer.org/installer` in browser? any output you are getting?

Comment: nope. its showing php code as it is

Comment: Can you try this one `php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('http://getcomposer.org/installer'));" `

Comment: This may help you `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545257/composer-install-for-windows` and `https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#general`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74895/discussion-between-firoz-and-sky).

Answer (score -1):

Try this
C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

Comment: tried this as well, showing the same error as mentioned above.